# cannot print struct contents stored in vector C++

Tags: c++

Hello guys I have problem when I have an array of student record which is struct by type. I have randomly assigned numbers to each of student during that I am storing each record in the vector. After that I want to sort it by marks. The problem is that iterator doesn't print the contents of vector. I believe problem is at statement`cout<<*RecVectorItr.Marks<<endl;` but I cannot figure out why. Can you point out what's wrong. Thank you in advance. Here is code

```
include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct Record
{
    int RollNum;
    char Name[20];
    float Marks;
    char Status[10];
};

bool compFunc (struct Record Rec1, struct Record Rec2)
{
    return (Rec1.Marks<Rec2.Marks); 
}

int main ()
{
    struct Record Students[20];
    float MarksArray[20]={30.4, 20.1, 11.9, 50.0, 55, 100, 11, 34, 90, 12, 13, 14, 19, 22.4, 88 , 56, 22, 78, 98, 29};
    vector<Record> RecVector;
    for (int i=1;i<21;i++)
    {
        Students[i].Marks=MarksArray[i];
        RecVector.push_back (Students[i]);
    }
    sort (RecVector.begin (), RecVector.end (), compFunc);
    for (vector<Record>::iterator RecVectorItr=RecVector.begin (); RecVectorItr!=RecVector.end ();RecVectorItr++)
        cout<<*RecVectorItr.Marks<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In C++ indexes are 0-based. Usually...

Comment: You mean the code doesn't compile. You have an operator precedence issue here: `*RecVectorItr.Marks`.

Comment: Yes the code doesn't compile. I am using dev-c++ it is giving this message 'class __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Record*, std::vector<Record, std::allocator<Record> > >' has no member named 'Marks'

Comment: Make it `RecVectorItr->Marks`

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not working due to a problem of [Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence):

> When parsing an expression, an operator which is listed on some row
>   will be bound tighter (as if by parentheses) to its arguments than any
>   operator that is listed on a row further below it.

Table that list the precedence can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Change your printing line with the following:

```
cout<<RecVectorItr->Marks<<endl;
```